Mayday Vivobook won't boot with ssd, live usb
On September, 2023 I installed Ubuntu 20.04 on a newly purchased Vivobook S 16X M5602QA-MB128. I've been using Ubuntu since 2012. I am IT-illiterate.
This Tuesday, December, 3 I allowed software update without looking what was there.
This Wednesday, December, 4 I powered on the Vivobook and read this:
could not create moklistrt: no response
could not create moklistxrt: no response
could not create moklistTrustedrt: no response
Something seriously went wrong: import_mok_state() failed: no response

I read online posts, disabled/enabled Secure Boot, deleted keys, attempted booting with bootable USB sticks (both made with Startup Disk Creator, the older one used in March to install Ubuntu for someone else's Vivobook and another one written yesterday).
I shall mention I regret I did Reset to Setup Mode for Key Management as the user suggested here https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/774195/could-not-create-moklistrt-volume-full-etc-when-trying-to-boot-almost-any-distr .
I was not able to restore the factory keys - loading boot variables is locked.
I was not able appending forbidden signatures - loading failed.
There is a file there which I have no copy of and is important.
@kyodake: Thank you, Sir. LiveCDRecovery you referred me to calls me to boot a LiveUsb burned with this ISO ubuntu.com/download. I’ve attempted booting with both 20.04 lts and 24.04 lts on Dec., 4-6 with no success. – sana Commented Dec 6 at 18:24
@Archisman Panigrahi: Thank you, Sir. I went to bios on Dec., 4, several times, yesterday I attempted booting without/with a USB more than a dozen times, and once again today, please, see: asus.com/support/faq/1013017. After I press F10 the book won’t boot and shows me asus logo. If I press escape, the book gives me those four menacing lines I saw first on Dec., 4. I am responding to your question with such a delay for most of the waking hours there is power outage and my slow asus eee pc (am fortunate to have it still kicking) has Ubuntu 16.04 lts and a dead battery. – sana Commented Dec 8 at 22:46
Addenda Dec., 12
for 8 days I have been attempting booting with two usbs I used for installing Ubuntu 22.04 lts and 20.04 lts back in September 2023. I had to install 20.04 because 22.04 was malfunctioning on the very first day. Both sticks were created with Disk Creator on my asus eee pc with Ubuntu 16.04 lts. February 2024 I used one of the sticks to successfully install Ubuntu on someone else’s newly purchased Vivobook. Last night I was shocked noticing while customizing boot options that Boot Menu [F8] still displays the manufacturer’s name of the stick I used for installing OS in September, 2023, so do Boot options in the advance menu [F7] when I am trying to prioritize UEFI removable device with another stick with another manufacturer’s name inserted into the book, btw I can prioritize only after I have created an option with the path to SSD directory. There is no other way I can see Boot Options directory.
I have just been able to see both sticks in legacy bios in my asus eee pc with Ubuntu 2016.
Do I understand it correct my new book can not recognize the sticks it used to do in Autumn 2023 any more? If so, why? What shall I do? I have just written to my asus regional tech support if my device uefi must get updated. They will answer in 48 hours, last time it took them 48 hours to write me they have nothing to do with Linux.
Addenda Dec., 13
my asus regional tech support instructed me to keep the power button for 60 s.
Will arranging ethernet provide me with any options?

See at: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/LiveCdRecovery

What happens when you attempt booting with the USB drive? You can use the live session to back up important files to another drive and then install Ubuntu

@user68186 I can't edit my both comments, neither I can see the way to integrate my responses to both gentlemen' suggestion and question into the details and circumstances I provided to support my question.

@user68186 Sir, my both answers to the gentlemen' question and suggestion are concise comprehensive and in their entirety serve the purpose of the answers. They are an integrous part of the exchange between the three of us. I can not separate the gentlemen' inquiry and my response. Please, add the gentlemen' inquiries into the details I provided for my question.

I have tried to recover form this bad update for two days. Now I'm going to do a fresh install of Ubuntu 24.
